Ordering Option List in Sitecore Content Hub not working
We have an existing Option list within Sitecore Content Hub DAM.
We made new items on this list and want to order it in a different way. But this is not being executed.
On further investigation once we try to reorder the list we get an JavaScript exception.
Uncaught TypeError: e.map is not a function
at s (OptionListDetailModal.tsx:245:36)
at X (OptionListDetailModal.tsx:258:25)
at onChange (OptionListValues.tsx:300:25)
at t.dragApply (Nestable.js:372:13)
at r.onDragEnd (Nestable.js:161:25)

The exception occurs on OptionListDetailModal.tsx:245 


Sitecore Support has confirmed the behavior.
It has been reported as a "bug" and has the reference of "MONE-46327".

Ya currently this is a bug on the Content Hub. But you can leverage Import/Export feature to change the order of items inside the option List.

Items of the option list are stored as the array inside the exported json file. You can reorder the values array property and again import the json file back to Content Hub, to change the order.

Hope this helps!!!

Thank you for this information I will consider it. Unfortunately I cannot let editors in CH let them do this every time they want changes to be done on a option list.

@DannyPaul yes not from editor point of view. But as a developer we can change the order until the issue from Content Hub side is resolved.
